ortools CVRP objective: minimize routes past a threshold
I know that the ortools CVRP module, by default, is designed to minimize the total distance traveled among all vehicles. In my case, I am primarily concerned about making sure a very high percentage of my routes are under a maximum time. Is there a way to change the algo's objective so that it tries to minimize the number of routes that go past a threshold time / distance?

Typically, you also want to do load balancing (fairness) across the cases that go above that maximum time. In that case, you'd rather have 5 vehicles doing 1 hour too much than 1 vehicle doing 4 hours too much.

Thanks @GeoffreyDeSmet any recommendations on how to do this with ortools? I know Timefold is a superior solution for these things, but my project timelines are short and I don't want to spend the time moving to a different solution.

Additionally @GeoffreyDeSmet it's preferable to have 1 vehicle doing 4 hours too much because my metric is ensuring the percentage of vehicles within the threshold is <= X%. So 5 vehicles breaking the cap at all, is worse than 1 vehicle breaking the cap bigly

That's anti load balancing then: Reward it instead of penalizing it in the objective function.

Usually the building-blocks to push your solutions into that direction are the following (i already filtered it a bit: see original headers)
  /// Sets an upper bound on the dimension span on a given vehicle. This is the
  /// preferred way to limit the "length" of the route of a vehicle according to
  /// a dimension.
  void SetSpanUpperBoundForVehicle(int64_t upper_bound, int vehicle);
  /// Sets a cost proportional to the dimension span on a given vehicle,
  /// or on all vehicles at once. "coefficient" must be nonnegative.
  /// This is handy to model costs proportional to idle time when the dimension
  /// represents time.
  /// The cost for a vehicle is
  ///   span_cost = coefficient * (dimension end value - dimension start value).
  void SetSpanCostCoefficientForVehicle(int64_t coefficient, int vehicle);
  void SetSpanCostCoefficientForAllVehicles(int64_t coefficient);
  /// Sets a cost proportional to the dimension total slack on a given vehicle,
  /// Sets a cost proportional to the *global* dimension span, that is the
  /// difference between the largest value of route end cumul variables and
  /// the smallest value of route start cumul variables.
  /// In other words:
  /// global_span_cost =
  ///   coefficient * (Max(dimension end value) - Min(dimension start value)).
  void SetGlobalSpanCostCoefficient(int64_t coefficient);


  /// Sets a piecewise linear cost on the cumul variable of a given variable
  /// index. If f is a piecewise linear function, the resulting cost at 'index'
  /// will be f(CumulVar(index)). As of 3/2017, only non-decreasing positive
  /// cost functions are supported.
  void SetCumulVarPiecewiseLinearCost(int64_t index,
                                      const PiecewiseLinearFunction& cost);

  /// Sets a soft upper bound to the cumul variable of a given variable index.
  /// If the value of the cumul variable is greater than the bound, a cost
  /// proportional to the difference between this value and the bound is added
  /// to the cost function of the model:
  ///   cumulVar <= upper_bound -> cost = 0
  ///    cumulVar > upper_bound -> cost = coefficient * (cumulVar - upper_bound)
  /// This is also handy to model tardiness costs when the dimension represents
  /// time.
  void SetCumulVarSoftUpperBound(int64_t index, int64_t upper_bound,
                                 int64_t coefficient);


The final decision what to use might not be easy as it depends on some specifics.
I think i partitioned the functions correctly to express the following important fact:

upper group based on span = end - start
lower group based on accumulation

typically formulated on cumul-vars dim.CumulVar(model->End(vehicle_index))



Using any of above will ask to provide a fitting transit-evaluator (e.g. transit-time + service-time).
